Calculate cash flow for payables from balance sheet
As I understand, part of operating cash flow statement is the changes in operating assets and liabilities. I'm looking at the financial statements of one of the US companies and I see that in cash flow statement there is one component - "Accounts payable".
I have learnt that to calculate "Accounts payable" for operating cash flow statement you need to take current and previous year's balance sheet figures for "Accounts payable" and simply subtract to get the figure for operating cash flow statement.
The problem is that from balance sheet I get a different value after subtraction from the one listed on operating cash flow statement corresponding to "Accounts payable"

How can I explain that difference? (can time frames be different for balance sheet and cash flow statement?)
And overall, is the information on balance sheet enough to construct the cash flow statement? (if not what kind of information is also needed? any examples? )

